# AVAssetReader failing after one frame on H.264 .mov file

Tags: ios, avfoundation

I'm trying to render an H.264 QuickTime movie to an OpenGL texture on iOS. I am stuck decoding frame buffers from the input file. One frame decodes correctly and displays. All subsequent calls to [AVAssetReaderTrackOutput getNextSample] return NULL, however, and AVAssetReader.status == AVAssetReaderStatusFailed. If I do not specify a value for kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey in the settings dict, the status remains AVAssetReaderStatusReading, but the buffer objects returned are empty. The AVAsset in question plays without issue in AVPlayer. Is there anything obviously wrong with my code?

```
- (id) initWithAsset: (AVAsset *) asset {
    if (!(self = [super init])) return nil;
    _asset = [asset copy];
    [self initReaderToTime:kCMTimeZero]; 
    return self;
}

- (void) initReaderToTime:(CMTime) readStartTime {  
    _readStartTime = readStartTime;

    NSMutableDictionary *outputSettings =  [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [outputSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA] forKey:(NSString *)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey];
    _trackOutput = [[AVAssetReaderTrackOutput alloc] initWithTrack:[[_asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] outputSettings:outputSettings];  

    NSError *error = nil;
    _assetReader = [[AVAssetReader alloc] initWithAsset:_asset error:&error];
    if (error) return; 

    if (![_assetReader canAddOutput:_trackOutput]) return;
    [_assetReader addOutput:_trackOutput];

    if (![_assetReader startReading]) return; 

    [self getNextSample];
}


- (void) getNextSample {
    if (_assetReader.status != AVAssetReaderStatusReading) { 
        Log(@"Reader status %d != AVAssetReaderStatusReading. Ending...", _assetReader.status);
        return; 
    }

    CMSampleBufferRef sampleBuffer = [_trackOutput copyNextSampleBuffer];

    /*
    Do things with buffer 
    */

    [self performSelector:_cmd withObject:nil afterDelay:0];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`[_trackOutput copyNextSampleBuffer]` should appear somewhere in your code.

Comment: Sorry, it does. I removed that when removing the unrelated code for this post. Editing now. The odd behavior is that the first call to copyNextSampleBuffer return a valid sample buffer (that I display successfully to the screen. All subsequent calls to copyNextSampleBuffer return null.

Comment: Have you set up an audio session with a mixable category?

Comment: OK, so the problem is that I am attempting to play an audio file with AVPlayer as I render the video. If I do not start AVPlayer, AVAssetReader works. It looks like they share global state! (Perhaps they both lock decoding hardware.) In any case, it looks like a need to find a lower level way to play the audio.

Comment: @wombat57 Is this shared state documented somewhere? I have a `UITableView` full of `AVPlayer`s, and I am trying to record a video in a modal view over it, but when I try to encoding it, it fails most of the time! I have no idea how to understand this error. When encoding, I use `[output copyNextSampleBuffer]`, and that call won't return at all. It simply hangs (not on UI-thread). If it has to do with the underlying `AVPlayer`s, that should be documented somewhere, right?

Comment: Not sure about documentation, but your UITableView of AVPlayers sounds a little heavy... I haven't pushed AVFoundation in a while, but more than a handful of AVPlayers in existence at a time sounds like a bad idea.